# Скрипт с участием ttyUSB1

Tags: shell

Возникла такая проблема : имеется модем 3g /dev/ttyUSB1 хочу написать скрипт который будит брать с модема всякие данные типа сигнала, режима 3г и тд в продолжительном изучение гугла наткнулся что можно делать так

```
> a=`echo -e "at+zrssi\r" > /dev/ttyUSB1 | sleep 3 | head -n 1 /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep RSSI`
```

но, такой запрос срабатывает ну примерно через раз бывает реже, зависает .
Может кто обьяснить, что  может быть или как еще можно отправлять запросы.

В minicom работает все четко, умельцы пишут что с php тоже все нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо разобрался

```
echo -e "at+zrssi\r" > /dev/ttyUSB1 && sleep 1| head -n 2 < /dev/ttyUSB1 | tail -n 2|grep ZRSSI:
```